# Perform all write operations using one DB with Django multiple databases

Tags: database, django, multiple-databases

In my django app I have a model with such method:

```
def deleteItem(self, item, pt):
        if pt == 'product':
            i = self.vcartitem_set.filter(product__id=item)
        elif pt == 'brand':
            i = self.vcartbrand_set.filter(brand__id=item)
        else:
            return u'Wrong product type'
        i.delete()
        return 'OK'
```

I have 2 databases, 'default' and 'slave'. Slave is read-only, so when **self.vcartitem_set.filter(product__id=item)** is performed using 'slave' database, I have an error on **i.delete()**. I can bypass this by writing **i.delete(using='default')**, but then I have to write that for every model. Is there a way to tell django to perform all write operations, using 'default' DB, even if objects were previously retrieved using 'slave' DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this using DB routers: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing

You just need to create a Router Model and define the db_for_read and db_for_write functions, add DATABASE_ROUTERS to your settings.py and it'll do the trick.